# Spyder ipkernel issues - Reload message

Tags: python, spyder

I've just started to code using Spyder on Windows 10. When I run the program directly through the start menu or anyway but prompt I keep get this message on Spyder console every time I run a script:

> Reloaded modules: ipykernel, ipykernel._version, ipykernel.connect, ipykernel.kernelapp, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, ipykernel.iostream, jupyter_client.session, jupyter_client.jsonutil, dateutil, dateutil._version, dateutil.parser, dateutil.parser._parser, six, dateutil.relativedelta, dateutil._common, dateutil.tz, dateutil.tz.tz, dateutil.tz._common, dateutil.tz._factories, dateutil.tz.win, dateutil.parser.isoparser, jupyter_client.adapter, ipykernel.heartbeat, ipykernel.ipkernel, IPython.utils.tokenutil, ipykernel.comm, ipykernel.comm.manager, ipykernel.comm.comm, ipykernel.kernelbase, tornado.queues, tornado.locks, ipykernel.jsonutil, ipykernel.zmqshell, IPython.core.payloadpage, ipykernel.displayhook, ipykernel.eventloops, ipykernel.parentpoller, win32api, win32security, ntsecuritycon, ipykernel.datapub, ipykernel.serialize, ipykernel.pickleutil, ipykernel.codeutil, IPython.core.completerlib, storemagic, autoreload, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model

I wish I could solve this, because start Spyder through prompt is taking like forever, but I don't know what i should look for. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This can only happen if you're using a quite Spyder version (more than two years old). Please update to our latest version (4.2.0), released a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

Tools > Preferences > Python Interpreter > deselect "Show reloaded modules list" under the User Module Reloader